# Trying to reference query term in Django ListView as a tile of page with many to many reference

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Long time reader, first time questioner. Thanks for all of your help.
I am trying to add a title to each page generated, for each  document tag. So, if it was tagged, "press release" the page would display a list of all the documents with that tag, and the header with the header "press release" at the top. for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to reference the tag in the template. Any help would be appreciated!

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Document, Tag
from django.views.generic import ListView

class DocumentList(ListView):

    template_name = 'documents/document_list.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    self.tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, name=self.kwargs['tag'])
    return Document.objects.filter(tags = self.tag)
```

Template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}


<div class= 'container'> 
<div class="panel panel-default">
<!-- Default panel contents -->
<div class="panel-heading">WHAT GOES HERE!?!</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<p>.These files will assist in</p>
</div>

<table class= '.table-responsive'>
{% for Document in object_list  %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ Document.name }}</td>

    <td>{{ Document.discription }}</td>

{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^(?P<tag>[\w-]+)/index/$', views.DocumentList.as_view(), name =     'documentlist'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in the template, you have to add it to the context. The best way to do that would be to define `get_context_data` on your view class:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(DocumentList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['tag'] = self.tag
    return context
```

Now you can access it in the template via `{{ tag }}`.